# How to create a child process with parent process as init process using Process Builder in Java

Tags: java, process, init

Is there any way to create a process through Process Builder in java with parent id as 1 and unix user is any other unix user except root user. I am developing a application in java (will run as root user)that will start, stop and monitor the process in unix operating system. I am using Process Builder in java to create  the process during start operation. The process parent id by default is the process id of my application. I need to make parent process id of these started process to be init process(ppid = 1). Because in case my application crashes or stops, these process which are started by my application still exists(i.e. do not stop). Because in current situation when ppid of these process is process id of my applcation, when my application goes down these process also automatically killed.

I am adding two cases here which i have observed regarding this behavior :
Here are two cases: 1) First is when i run my application with root user and then create sub process with process builder in java , in this case the child process will take ppid as my application id but when i kill my application , the ppid of child process become 1(init process) but child process is running by root user (which i  don't want , it should be run under another Unix user).

2) In case 2 , when i run my application by another Unix user except root user , then when i kill my application , the child process also get killed.

But i need same behavior as in first case i.e it should continue running with ppid  1 but should run under my Unix user(not root user).

Comment: Unfortunately no. The JVM has no access to such low level system calls...

Comment: What you are talking about is not a standard behavior. Java processes are independent, there is no bond that would kill child process if parent dies. I think that trying to change the ppid of your newly created process(which is IMHO even not possible) is not the way to go